# Python returns wrong truth table for logical implication

Tags: python, boolean-logic, discrete-mathematics

[image]

I have implemented the above implication in Python but it does not return the expected results:

```
  True       True None
  True      False None
 False       True True
 False      False None
```

My python code is:

```
def implies(a,b):
    if a:
        return b
    else:True
    return
for p in (True, False):
    for q in (True, False):
        print("%10s %10s %s" %(p,q,implies((p or q) and (not p), q)))
```

I don't understand the contradiction here. None implies False doesn't it? And why not print True like it should?

Comment: `else: True` should be `else: return True`. As is it doesn't do anything.

Comment: Looks like you can replace the implementation of `implies` with the value `True`, if every result is expected to be `T`.

Comment: Thank you guys, this function was actually provided in an exercise so I didnt look twice into it!

Comment: Simply `return not a or b` will do the trick as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def implies(a,b):
    if a:
        return b
    else:True
    return
```

Your error is in the last two lines, if !a, you aren't returning a specific value, so the result is `None`.
You want:

```
def implies(a,b):
    if a:
        return b
    else:
        return True
```